# Binding text value to another property of view model when using a dropdown

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to display an observable array in a dropdown, and when the user selects the option, I want to present a property of that view model. It seems simple. I have provided code and a link to Fiddle.

HTML:

```html
<select data-bind="options: oCountries, 
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   optionsValue: 'isocode', 
                   value: selectedCountry">
</select>

Controlled by <span data-bind="value: selectedCountry.isocode"></span>
```

JS:

```
var countries = [{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "isocode": "AF",
    "language": "English",
    "crmdatacontroller": "CRM India"
}, {
    "name": "Aland Islands",
    "isocode": "AX",
    "language": "Finnish",
    "crmdatacontroller": "CRM Finland"
}]

var viewModel = {
    oCountries: ko.observableArray(countries),
    selectedCountry: ko.observableArray(['AX'])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxNrt/24)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `optionsValue` parameter controls what is written by the `value` binding.  So, in your case, it will write the `isocode` to `selectedCountry`.

So, the simplest changes to your code would be to set selectedCountry to a normal observable and the appropriate isocode.  Then, have your span use the `text` binding against `selectedCountry`.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wxNrt/21/

Now, a couple other options available to you as well:
-if you leave off `optionsValue` in the binding, then it will set/read the object directly.  In that case, you need to change how you are intially setting it.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxNrt/23/

-if you want to send/receive a key (like the isocode), then you can use `optionsValue`, but set up a dependentObservable to represent the actual object like:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxNrt/22/

-if you are dealing with a multi-select situation, then you want to use the `selectedOptions` binding instead of `value`, as described here:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

Comment: Amazing, Thank you for the quick response and even better the explanation of how you got to the answer. The different scenerios really helped me to understand knockoutjs better. The solution I needed for the current project is http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wxNrt/2/ . But will be referencing this post in the future for sure.

Comment: @axrwkr Thanks for updating. fiddle has evolved and changed things a bit. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your markup to this:

```
<select data-bind="options: oCountries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'isocode', value: selectedCountry">
</select>
Controlled by <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry"></span>
```

And the script:

```
var countries = [
{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "isocode": "AF",
    "language": "English",
    "crmdatacontroller": "CRM India"},
{
    "name": "Aland Islands",
    "isocode": "AX",
    "language": "Finnish",
    "crmdatacontroller": "CRM Finland"}
]

var viewModel = {
    oCountries: ko.observableArray(countries),
    selectedCountry: ko.observable('AX')
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuJpS/11/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but not quite what I was looking for. I wanted to display a property of the country other than the key.